# Cannot compile critic2 using libxc. cmake says different compiler

Tags: compiling, libraries, cmake

```bash
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLIBXC_DIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxc.so ..
-- A library with BLAS API found.
-- Could NOT find NUMDIFF (missing: NUMDIFF_EXE) 
-- Found libxc (lib=/usr/local/lib/libxcf90.a /usr/local/lib/libxc.a | inc=/usr/local/include) but could not compile against it (different compiler?)
-- Could NOT find LIBCINT (missing: LIBCINT_LIBRARY LIBCINT_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
-- Could NOT find NLOPT (missing: NLOPT_INCLUDE_DIRS NLOPT_LIBRARIES)
```

Comment: `LIBXC_DIR`: this reads **very** much like it should be a **dir**ectory containing the library, not the library.

Comment: Also, terrible style of the CMake scripting to require you to specify that manually; detecting libraries is the whole point of using a meta-build system like CMake.